# SPI MOSI receive error

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, arduino-ide, communication, spi

I have a master and a slave (both are arduino UNO) connected through SPI connected. I want to transmit a character to the slave and receive true or false to the master. The transmission is working perfectly. If I send `'2'`, slave is receiving `'2'`. When I try to transmit an integer from slave to master, the master is always receiving some arbitrary number like 128 or 255.

Master Code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Master");
  digitalWrite(SS,HIGH);
  SPI.begin();
  SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV8);
}
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(SS,LOW);  //  Slave select to low
  received1 = SPI.transfer(test);  // test is a variable which is '2'. The data received by master is stored in received1 variable which is char.
  Serial.println(received1);  
  digitalWrite(SS,HIGH);  
}
```

Slave code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Slave");
  pinMode(MISO,OUTPUT);
  SPCR |= _BV(SPE);
  process = false;
  SPI.attachInterrupt();  
}
ISR(SPI_STC_vect){
  received = SPDR;  // the data received by slave is slored in **received** variable(the variable is char type)
  Serial.println(received);
  process = true;
}
void loop() {
  if(process){
    SPDR = jj;  // Updating SPDR to send data from slave. jj is char type
    process = false;
  } 
}
```

Comment: The most important part, declaration of variable `process`, is not here. Is it volatile? Also do you realize that SPDR on slave must be set before the master starts transmission?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning about `process`. It's a `boolean` variable which will be true when something is received by slave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for this problem in a blog.

Link: http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=10892

I modified my master code and got my desired result.

Master code:

```
byte transferAndWait (const byte what)
{
  byte a = SPI.transfer (what);
  delayMicroseconds (2000);
  return a;
} // end of transferAndWait

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(SS,LOW);
  transferAndWait (10);  
  received1 = transferAndWait (11);
  digitalWrite(SS,HIGH);
  Serial.println(received1);
}
```

The response will be "collected" next time through the loop. That's why we need to keep a dummy `transferAndWait()` function first and then the result of that transfer will be stored in `received1` variable.

Comment: Please accept your own answer if it solved your problem, otherwise Stack Exchange throws it up from time to time as an unsolved question.